# Which stage make difference between call-by-name and call-by-value?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

Most of other language use call-by-value. Haskell use call-by-name (lazy evaluation), I'm wonder how does it runs and I think it will be better compare with call-by-value.

Take a example with the question,
the repeat' function defined as this:

```
repeat' :: a -> [a]   
repeat' x = x:repeat' x
```

use `repeat' 3` will get a unlimited list of 3,
`ghci> repeat' 3` will generate 3 continuous,
 but `take 5 (repeat' 3)` will just get `[3,3,3,3,3]`.
how does the haskell know end with fifth recursion inner `repeat'` function? Besides, I don't think it's a matter of `take`.

When the code be executed which stage it difference with call-by-value?

thanks

Comment: In short, always reduce the outermost expression, which is reducible: `head (repeat 3)` -> `head (3:repeat 3)` -> `3`. In the first case, `head` is not reducible because it must pattern match on its argument, but its argument is *not* a constructor. However, `repeat` does no pattern matching, so it can always be reduced. After the first reduction, `head` can now be reduced, because there is a constructor (the `:`).

Comment: "When the code be executed which stage it difference with call-by-value? " erm... what?   Are you asking something like: *Assuming that instead of call-by-name we used call-by-value as strategy for passing function parameters, would this make a difference?* I believe that for call-by-value you actually mean eager reduction, in which case `repeat 3` is simply `undefined` and so `take 5 undefined = undefined` and the program would get stuck forever.

Comment: @Bakuriu,you can consider call-by-name as lazy evaluation(it will be better to comprehension).call-by-value will be used when expression could be evaluation as long as complier can, of course, Haskell not use call-by-value.  I don't understand  you said **repeat 3 is simply undefined** and  which point it will be evaluated.most of other language (such as c/c++)use call-by-value, I want to know how does Haskell deal with `undefined`(repeat 3)? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an unlimited list of 3s because typing `repeat' 3` in an interactive session essentially calls `show (repeat' 3)`, and `show` tries to iterate over the entire return value of `repeat' 3`. `take`, on the other hand, only tries to get a finite number of elements from the list. Here's a definition from the Prelude:

```
take n _      | n <= 0 =  []
take _ []              =  []
take n (x:xs)          =  x : take (n-1) xs
```

Compare the definition of `repeat'`, `repeat' x = x:repeat' x` with the pattern matched by take. When you call `take 5 (repeat' 3)`, the last pattern applies, so it becomes `take 5 (3:repeat' 3) = 3 : take 4 (repeat' 3)`. Due to lazy evaluation, `repeat'` is only evaluated as much as necessary at any given step, which in this case means extracting the first element to match the pattern `x:xs`. Thus, `take` builds up a list of 5 3's, terminating when `take 0 (repeat' 3)` matches and the recursion terminates, ignoring the unevaluated call to `repeat'` to return an empty list.

Comment: Do you mean to say `take` treated 3s as empty list at the beginning?but when `take` try access `repeat 3`,the expression wouldn't be evaluation?

Comment: It never treats `(repeat' 3)` as an empty list; rather, it never looks at anything other than the head at any point in time. The unevaluated tail is passed to the recursive calls.

Comment: Furthermore,Which point the unevaluated tail be evaluated inner `take`?